# Ruby on rails: How to pass checkbox values to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I want to use checkboxes for rating a book.

I want to have 5 integers and for each a checkbox. Only one can be checked. 
Like:
1
2
3
4
5

and next to each a checkbox.

Those integers don't directly correspond to any value in the database.

How exactly can I do this in my view and how can I use the checked values in my controller? I want to check which one is selected and then update the value of the rating in the database.

My view code:

```
<div class="book-2 book-text col-8">
    <h2><%= @book.title %></h2>

    <p>Rate book:</p>
 <div>
```

Controller:

```
def detailedbook
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

My Rates model:

```
    class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :rates do |t|
      t.integer "user_id", null: false
      t.integer "book_id", null: false
      t.float "rating", null: false
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :rates
  end
end
```

My book model:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string "title", null: false
      t.float "rating", default: 0
      t.string "source"
      t.integer "published"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :books
  end
end
```

I want to create a new instance of object Rates, if the user with user_id hasn't rated the book before. If he has, I would just update the value of rating in Rates model for this user. Then I would also update the rating for a specific book altogether (sum of all rates / number of all rates).

Comment: If only one can be submitted, you should use radio inputs instead

Comment: You can do it with radio buttons instead. Could you provide some code of your view/controller?

Comment: Didn't even know they existed, thanks.
I updated my question with some code. If you can help me with any part of my question it would be great :)

Comment: I'd use AJAX - on some rating click send that `rating`, the `user_id` and the `book_id` values to some method, and put it in the table. Are you using devise maybe?

Comment: I don't know what devise is , so I suppose I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem "ratyrate" to make the work more easy

Add the ratyrate gem into your Gemfile

```
gem 'ratyrate'
```

Next step, run these commands:

```
rails g ratyrate user
rake db:migrate
```

Include these Javascript:

```
//= require jquery.raty
//= require ratyrate
```

You should add the ratyrate_rateable function with its dimensions option. You can add multiple dimensions.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rateable "speed", "engine", "price"
end
```

Then you need to add a call ratyrate_rater in the user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rater
end
```

Using

There is a helper method which name is rating_for to add the star links. By default rating_for will display the average rating and accept the new rating value from authenticated user.

```
<%# show.html.erb -> /cars/1 %>

Speed  : <%= rating_for @car, "speed" %>
Engine : <%= rating_for @car, "engine" %>
Price  : <%= rating_for @car, "price" %>
```

For more information, you can visit the Gem Repo https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate.